# Checked Radio Button Inside Echo In PHP

Tags: php

How i can checked radio button inside echo method ?

```
<?php
      if(isset($_GET['sid'])){



          echo' 

    <div class="right_col" role="main">';
          $a=$_GET['sid'];
          $update = $obj->selectdata($a);

          foreach($update as $upd)
          {
               $upd['sname'];
          echo' 
        <h1 class="text-center">update student</h1>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-8">
                <form class="form-horizontal" action="dashboard.php?sid='.$upd['id'].'" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Name</label>
                        <input type="text" value="'.$upd['sname'].'" name="sname" required class="form-control"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Father Name</label>
                        <input type="text" value="'.$upd['sfname'].'" name="sfname"  required class="form-control"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Email</label>
                        <input type="email" value="'.$upd['email'].'" name="semail"  required class="form-control"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Password</label>
                        <input type="password" name="spass" placeholder="Change Password"  required class="form-control"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Date Of Birth</label>
                        <input type="date" value="'.$upd['dob'].'" name="sdob"  required class="form-control"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Gender</label>

                    <div class="radio-inline">

                        <label><input type="radio" name="sgender" if($s_gender == Male){echo checked=checked}  value="Male" />Male</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="radio-inline">
                    <label><input type="radio" name="sgender" if($s_gender == Female){echo checked=checked} value ="Female" />Female</label>
                    </div></div>





                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Contact</label>
                        <input type="text" name="scontact" value="'.$upd['contact'].'"  required class="form-control"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Address</label>
                        <input type="text" name="saddress"  value="'.$upd['address'].'" required class="form-control"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Photo</label>
                        <input type="file" name="spic"  required class="form-control"/>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" name="upt_form" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>';


          }
      }
      else {
      echo'

    <div class="right_col" role="main">
          <h1 class="text-center">add student</h1>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-8">
                <form class="form-horizontal" action="dashboard.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Name</label>
                        <input type="text" name="sname" required class="form-control"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Father Name</label>
                        <input type="text" name="sfname"  required class="form-control"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Email</label>
                        <input type="email" name="semail"  required class="form-control"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Password</label>
                        <input type="password" name="spass"  required class="form-control"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Date Of Birth</label>
                        <input type="date" name="sdob"  required class="form-control"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Gender</label>

                    <div class="radio-inline">
                        <label><input type="radio" name="sgender" value="Male" required/>Male</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="radio-inline">
                    <label><input type="radio" name="sgender" value ="Female"required />Female</label>
                    </div></div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Contact</label>
                        <input type="text" name="scontact"  required class="form-control"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Address</label>
                        <input type="text" name="saddress"  required class="form-control"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Photo</label>
                        <input type="file" name="spic"  required class="form-control"/>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" name="stu_form" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>';
      }
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Work like this:

```
<input type="radio" '.($s_gender == Female ? 'checked="checked"' : "").' name="sgender"  value ="Female" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  if(isset($_GET['sid'])){



      echo' 

<div class="right_col" role="main">';
      $a=$_GET['sid'];
      $update = $obj->selectdata($a);

      foreach($update as $upd)
      {
           $upd['sname'];
      echo' 
    <h1 class="text-center">update student</h1>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-8">
            <form class="form-horizontal" action="dashboard.php?sid='.$upd['id'].'" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Name</label>
                    <input type="text" value="'.$upd['sname'].'" name="sname" required class="form-control"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Father Name</label>
                    <input type="text" value="'.$upd['sfname'].'" name="sfname"  required class="form-control"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Email</label>
                    <input type="email" value="'.$upd['email'].'" name="semail"  required class="form-control"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="spass" placeholder="Change Password"  required class="form-control"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Date Of Birth</label>
                    <input type="date" value="'.$upd['dob'].'" name="sdob"  required class="form-control"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Gender</label>

                <div class="radio-inline">
 if($upd['gender']== "Male") { 
 echo '
                    <label><input cheacked= "cheacked" type="radio" name="sgender"   value="Male" />Male</label>
</div>';
 }
 else {

  echo'              <div class="radio-inline">
                <label><input type="radio" cheacked= "cheacked" name="sgender" value ="Female" />Female</label>
                </div></div>';
 }





                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Contact</label>
                    <input type="text" name="scontact" value="'.$upd['contact'].'"  required class="form-control"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Address</label>
                    <input type="text" name="saddress"  value="'.$upd['address'].'" required class="form-control"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Photo</label>
                    <input type="file" name="spic"  required class="form-control"/>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" name="upt_form" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>';


      }
  }
  else {
  echo'

<div class="right_col" role="main">
      <h1 class="text-center">add student</h1>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-8">
            <form class="form-horizontal" action="dashboard.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="sname" required class="form-control"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Father Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="sfname"  required class="form-control"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Email</label>
                    <input type="email" name="semail"  required class="form-control"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="spass"  required class="form-control"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Date Of Birth</label>
                    <input type="date" name="sdob"  required class="form-control"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Gender</label>

                <div class="radio-inline">
                    <label><input type="radio" name="sgender" value="Male" required/>Male</label>
                </div>
                <div class="radio-inline">
                <label><input type="radio" name="sgender" value ="Female"required />Female</label>
                </div></div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Contact</label>
                    <input type="text" name="scontact"  required class="form-control"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Address</label>
                    <input type="text" name="saddress"  required class="form-control"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Photo</label>
                    <input type="file" name="spic"  required class="form-control"/>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" name="stu_form" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>';
  }
    ?>
```

use this code then let me know if it resolved your issue, you had to put if and else with your problem in proper way you used wrong variable for get gender value.